# How to fix error "could not initialize WinDbg engine" in ida pro 7.5?

Tags: reverse, windbg, ida, dbg

I get this error when i am trying to run the debugger:

[image: Error when i am trying to run the debugger]

I already wrote the path to the debugger in `ida.cfg`.

The problem was in Russian characters in the file path.

Comment: the error means ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT, so make sure you use correct windbg exe (32 vs 64bit)

Comment: @magicandre1981 windbg located in this folder is 32 bit. Or is it not enough?

Comment: there are a 64bit and 32bit IDA.exe, so make sure you select the correct windbg version

Comment: @magicandre1981 https://imgur.com/a/IYR4sAa . This message shows when i am trying to write the way to x64 debugger. Btw the file I am analyzing is 32 bit

Comment: ok, so open 32bit ida and select 32bit windbg

Comment: @magicandre1981 then I get an error which in the first screenshot

Comment: [the documentation says](https://hex-rays.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/debugging_windbg.pdf) you need to use the x86 windbg for 32 and 64 bit IDA.

Comment: @magicandre1981 i solved the problem. It was due to non-unicode characters in the file path

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks for the help

Comment: ok, what is your language? Russian? Post the steps that fixed it as an answer to help other users to find the solution

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes, there were Russian symbols. what steps do you mean if it is solved by renaming the directory?

Comment: yes post that the russian name was the cause and that renaming it to english name fixed it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 like this?

Comment: don't edit your question. [Post it as answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with explanations so that people can find it on internet search. comments are not so easy to find

Comment: @magicandre1981 ?

Comment: add some more details. Was the path to your debug target or the install location of IDA in russian?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in Russian characters in the path to debug file.

Comment: Didn't work. I moved the file to the drive's root directory and it still shows the error.